# Simple Cursor Adapter sections

Tags: android

I am using simple cursor adapter to populate the listview. My data is coming from sqlyte database and i have two coumns. how do i add sections (headers) in listview.

i searched a lot but could'nt find proper sections examples using simple cursor adapter. Any help is greatly appreciated. here is my example.

startManagingCursor(cursor);

```
String[] from = {"Label","_id"};

int[] to = new int[]{R.id.Text1};

SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

I need to add sections e.g

Section 1
Orange
Banana
Apple
Sextion 2
red
blue
black
Section 3
breakfast
lunch

Comment: You have to make a custom adapter to solve this. Just follow the standard Android guides for making custom adapters based on an ArrayAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html and custom views http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite difficult to do as you need to remap your cursor positions. There is a library that can help do this for you. The following is code that you can use to implement alphabetical sections with this library.

```
@Override 
protected Object getSectionFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Label");
    String name = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    return name.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1); 
}
```

Also check out the sample app where they sort their employees by department.

https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter

Comment: A blog post about this library has also been created. http://toastdroid.com/2014/05/09/adding-sections-to-cursoradapter/